# Using LaTeX packages in R presentations

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rpres

I understand that using the "header-includes" option in the YAML front matter of an Rmarkdown document allows the inclusion of LaTeX packages ([details here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown)), but how is this done for an Rstudio R presentation?

Comment: You should give a minimal example of such a presentation.

Comment: That's a bit fussy. A minimal example of an R presentation is an empty presentation in Rstudio. I.e., in Rstudio: File -> New File -> R Presentation.

Comment: That gives a Markdown presentation that produces HTML, it doesn't use LaTeX at all.  So you can't make use of LaTeX packages without some equivalent of `output: pdf_document`, and I don't know a way to add that in an R presentation.  I was assuming you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  If you want to use LaTeX packages, you need to be using LaTeX, and R Presentations don't.

You can generate presentations in PDF that use LaTeX using the Beamer option to R Markdown presentations.  With those the methods on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown will work.